# Since future-tech is offtopic, but Siri is a hot topic, is it on topic or off?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Announced but not yet released products](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/825/announced-but-not-yet-released-products)

Simple enough, yet nuanced. Since future-tech is off-topic, but Siri is a hot topic, is it on-topic or off?

Here's my reasons why it is on-topic:

- This is going to be asked in the near future as people are ready for the launch of 4S.
- The web (or this site) needs a good canonical answer.
- It may drive traffic here.
- It will be asked again (so says my experience).

So, even though the 4S and iOS 5 isn't here yet, is asking what Siri is and how do you pronounce it, etc., on-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the software and the phones are announced and will be shipping next week, it's OK for people to start asking questions about them.